# JavaScript RegEx Syntax Highlighting

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a jQuery plugin to highlight C++ code on my webpages. I'm not really too good with RegEx, so I can't figure out how to highlight keywords (like 'if', 'case', 'void', etc.) without highlighting parts of words (Like the 'int' in 'Paint'). I changed it a bit, but some things still don't get highlighted. This is what my RegEx looks like:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp("([' ' || \t ||,|| \"\"])(" + ParserKeywordsArr[i] + ")", 'g'), "$1<span style='color:" + ParserColorsArr[i] + ";'>" + ParserKeywordsArr[i] + "</span>");
```

This goes through every keyword I want highlighted, which is stored in an array, and theres another array with the colors (Ex. ParserKeywordsArr[0] is void, ParserColorsArr[0] is blue, so it would highlight in blue). However, when I put in something like this:

```
void CCodeEditorCtrl::OnPaint(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return;
}
```

Return gets highlighted, but void doesn't. I don't know how to tell RegEx "If its the first word on the line, and it matches a keyword, highlight it"

Comment: You'll need to get good with Regex for this project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the source of [Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter), which does by the way highlight C++ among other languages. I think you'll also find [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) helpful for testing them.

Comment: I'll look into those. I was just using notepad for testing, although I believe JavaScript has different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is a word break.

```
/in/.test('loading'); // => true
/\bin\b/.test('loading'); // => false
/\bin\b/.test('load.in.g'); // => true
```